Why mobile phones can record at such higher frame rates?
I know the comparison between mobile phones and 'proper' cameras (DSLR and mirrorless) can be controversial, and my question may seem silly but,
When I was looking for cameras that can record in 240fps or even 180fps at least, I was struggling to come across any. Cameras like the Canon R5 would only record in 120fps max. And I wanted to know why ? As this seems very low, when comparing to phones, my old phone can do 240fps 1080 and even 960fps. Why is there such a difference in this, I know phones are for all round purpose, but for a very expensive camera it seems low, is it because in the real pro photography world anything above 120fps isn't really needed ? Is it hard to have high FPS with bigger sensors ?
Thanks

This question is about video in a context that is not likely to be relevant to still photography.

I haven't researched, so not an answers, but maybe phone sensors have heavier duty readout circuitry at the expense of light sensitivity, since they know they'll be used for a lot of video.

Possible reason: big sensor + high frame rate = gobs of data.
So, one problem is the data rate to the storage medium, and another is the sustainable data rate to the storage medium.
Smartphones can have an edge (internal memory is possibly faster than good SD cards or Flash disks) but to produce a given playback quality at 30fps, you still have to encode at 8x the bitrate that you would use when recording a 30fps... A reasonable 6Mb/s require 48Mb/s when encoding.
You can compensate by using a high compression ratio, but when you do so you reduce the quality of individual frames. And people who invest in DSLR/ML cameras like quality photography, so there is only so much to gain there. What is the bit rate of your 240fps video, when played at normal speed?
Then, people with dedicated cameras may expect to shoot for a longer time. What is the maximum duration of a 240fps sequence on your smartphone?

I understand now, cheers.

It's not the size of the sensor, it is the resolution of the video stream that has to be processed.
The main reason phone cameras can record higher frame rates is because they use tricks to accomplish it. They may drop the resolution (i.e. 4k instead of 8k), they may line skip, and they may frame skip. In the latter two cases they typically interpolate (add artificially) the missing lines/frames when the video is processed.
At the higher end that kind of trickery is less acceptable. And high resolution cameras that are capable of high frame rates natively (without interpolation) are expensive.

thanks, much appreciated
